# v2.80: Keyboard Shortcut for Import / Export STL Files

Tags: export, import, shortcut

I tried to find a way to abondon the slow mouse action on importing and exporting STL files... The keymap seems not have mapping for import/export...

For the export I normally use the export button within the 3d printing toolbox (great plugin btw!) but a keyboard shortcut to export the selected object(s) would be sooo helpful..

Any ideas?

Best Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fastest way is to <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on *Export STL* button and choose *Assign a shortcut*. You can press nothing and click outside the area to leave it as an empty keymap entry.

[image]

After you assign a shortcut to it, go into setting panel and the keymap setting, the setting of *Export/Import* will be included in *Window* group:

[image]

You can assign different key maps for it, and also set any option that you can find in the exporting panel. The options will appear greyed out, which indicate that it is using default parameters. You can click on any of them to change the setting and override it. In your case, check the *Selection Only* button.